# Is setInterval cleared on scene change Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Are all setIntervals cleared on scene change in Phaser 3? For example, if I have this code:

```
class ExampleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  preload () {

  }
  create () {
    setInterval(() => console.log(true), 1000);
  }
  update () {
  
  }
}
```

and I change scenes, will it continue to log `true` to the console? Is there an alternative in Phaser that doesn't require that I remove all intervals manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, **No**. Since `setInterval` is a javascript function.
For details on the function: [here in the documentation on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

What you can do is "save" the `setInvertal` calls/id's in a list and clear them on a specific `scene` event like, **shutdown**, **pause**, **destroy** ... . When that event fires you can then stop all saved intervals, or so ([details to possible Scene events](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.Events.html)).
This is also considered *good practice*, since you always should cleanup resources, when *leaving* a phaser scene.

**Example *(here with the shutdown event)*:**

```js
 ...
 // setup list for the intervals, that should be cleared later
 constructor () {
    super();
    this.intervals = [];
  }

 create () {
     ...
     // example of adding an interval, so that I can be cleanup later
     this.intervals.push(setInterval(() => console.log(true), 1000));
     ...

     // example listening to the shutdown Event
     this.events.on('shutdown', this.stopAllIntervals, this);
 }
 ...
 // example "cleanup"-function, that is execute on the 'shutdown' Event
 stopAllIntervals(){
     for(let interval of this.intervals){
          clearInterval(interval);
     }
 }
 ...
```

And now you just hat to call the `stopAllIntervals`in the desired event function, when you want to stop them all.

> **From the offical documenation, on the shutdown Event:** *... You should free-up any resources that may be in use by your Scene in this event handler, on the understanding that the Scene may, at any time, become active again. A shutdown Scene is not 'destroyed', it's simply not currently active. Use the DESTROY event to completely clear resources. ...*